# mongoose.findByIdAndUpdate will only save the first key-value of object being pushed into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a simple object that stores two values inside, each being a req.body value from data sent from client.

```
const pushedVote = {
      answer: req.body.answer, 
      text: req.body.value
    }
```

Now, when I call the `findByIdAndUpdate` method it looks like this (with Poll being my model)

```
//insert answer and text 
    await Poll.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
      $push: {
        responseAnswers: pushedVote,
      },
    });
```

This all works fine, but what's weird is that the array in my database that is updated will ONLY store the first key-value pair in the object. For example, if the pushedVote object that is being stored had answer as 'A' and text as 'Cat', the database will only store 'A', and not 'Cat' along with it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I assume that `responseAnswers` is an array of votes? If so, it might better to do this in 3 steps to keep things clean.

1. `const poll = awat Poll.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id) });`

2. `poll.responseAnswers.push(pushedVote);`

3. `await poll.save();`

Comment: @KingJ that also works, but the same thing is happening. In my database, the object pushed into the ```responseAnswers``` array only contains the answer key and not both the answer and text key

Comment: And have you confirmed that `req.body.value` exists in the request and is available in the `pushedVote` object before you update the database? The other thing to check would be whether your schema supports that `text` property.

Comment: @Kingj wow I can't believe I forgot to add that text property in the schema. Thanks for the help

Comment: No worries! Glad it's sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, make sure that the `text` property is defined in the Mongoose schema, otherwise it won't be saved to the database.